# Symfony2 response rendering

Tags: php, symfony, response

Is it possible to add parameters to response

```
$response = $this->render('AcmeSiteBundle:Page:home.html.twig', array(
            'name' => 'tom',
        ));
```

And latter add some more parameters. Something like:

```
$response->addParameters(array(
            'lastname' => 'cruise'
        ));

...
return $response;
```

Is there a way that would work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the render method executes the twig templating engine and renders the template, which gets returned as text in a response. The response don't even know that the string was build by twig with some parameters/variables.

What you can do is having a `$params` variable containing the parameters, add some parameters to that array and use it in the end to generate the template:

```
$params = array(
    'firstname' => 'Joe'
);

// ...
$params['lastname'] = 'Doe';

return $this->render(..., $params);
```